# PHP hack to use post ID inside a query from previous form

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I am trying to post the data from a form submitted on the last page by each ID of the available posts on the current page. I thought this ought to work on the wordpress platform but it hasn't any ideas. the_ID() is a wordpress shortcode for picking up the current post ID.

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=services'); while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
        $title = $_POST["product_title_PRI_".the_ID()];
echo $title ;?>
```

Marvellous

ANSWER get_the_ID()

Comment: When you find the answer yourself, please actually answer the question instead of editing the question to include the answer. It's more in keeping with SO's format, plus it saves people time by not having to check questions that are already answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=services'); while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
        $title = $_POST["product_title_PRI_".get_the_ID()];
echo $title ;?>
```